# unity --reset is crashing

Tags: ubuntu-unity

When I fire command `unity --reset` it crashes.
How do I fix it?

```
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 1
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Window created on XQueryTree, map state isViewable? 0
Initializing bailer options...done
Initializing detection options...done
Initializing composite options...done
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: File a [bug report.](https://bugs.launchpad.net/unity)

Comment: I dont have an answer, but from what Ive read about Unity is that is extremely buggy.  I tried it for a bit and couldnt stand it.  Personally, I think it is a horrible interface.  I just log in with Gnome.